# Android 10 user CA file not being used in apps

Tags: xiaomi, android-10, certificates, https

I'm using an ISP that does internet filtering for me, I have install their CA file, and it works in the browser, and used to work in all apps.
After the latest update for Xiaomi Redmi Pro 9, Youtube, Spotify, etc. seem to be unable to load network resources.

I get this error on `logcat`

```
09-16 13:17:40.116 29069 29229 E GoogleConversionReporter: bffy: Exception in CronetUrlRequest: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID, ErrorCode=11, InternalErrorCode=-202, Retryable=false
09-16 13:17:40.116 29069 29229 E GoogleConversionReporter:      at org.chromium.net.impl.CronetUrlRequest.onError(PG:59)
```

Meaning the chromium component fails, or refuses, to use my user specified CA.
Is this on purpose? Is this a bug? I really don't want a VPN installed on my device to be able to use my own ISP.

Comment: User CA files are by default ignored by all apps (unless an app explicitly allows user certificates). This is by design since about Android 6.

Comment: Thing is, it DID work for me on Android 10 before the last update. Is there no way to force apps to use the user certificate without rooting and adding it as a system certificate? Works for me on another device I have, using Android 9. I just don't really want to root this device and start messing with it.
Also, it does work for Brave and Chrome for browsing.

Comment: Found an answer, it is described here https://github.com/YTVanced/Vanced/issues/45